# How to test if a particular C++ statement is faster or slower than other?

Tags: c++, optimization

For example when printing a single character like a new line character, which might be faster while using `cout` in C++, passing as string or as character?

```
cout << "\n";
```

Or

```
cout << '\n';
```

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFv7XwgsdLY) motivated me to write efficient codes.

How would you go about testing such things? Maybe I might want to test other things to see which is faster so it would be helpful to know how I can test these things myself.

Comment: The key part of the question is "*..how would you go about testing it?*"; however, it's a bit buried so expect some reactionary 'premature optimization' down-votes. Regardless, it would probably be beneficial to start with some "C++ benchmark" web searches - if nothing else it allows one to bring more to the table, such as 'unexpected outcomes'.

Comment: Can you help me improve the question? I see now, that exactly is what I wanted to know.

Comment: I hope the minimal title edits are enough to minimize pre-reading judgement. Good luck :)

Comment: You can certainly use any profiler to see what happens in both cases. However having just one line won't show any visible difference most likely. You'll need a larger test program producing larger amount of output, and still it will pretty much depend on standard library implementation you're using. This particular case is probably not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In theory*, **yes**, using *`'\n'`* instead of *`"\n"`* is quite faster when took out the elapsed time of printing *1000* occurrences of the same *good-ol* new-line:

> **Remember:** *A single char possibly cannot be slower than a pointer... since a pointer points to addresses of each char (like a container) and this is why its byte size is not **fixed**, and a char only has one address and that is itself... of only **1 byte***

```
// Works with C++17 and above...
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template<typename T, typename Duration = std::chrono::milliseconds, typename ...Args>
constexpr static auto TimeElapsedOnOperation(T&& functor, Args&&... arguments)
{
    auto const ms = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::invoke(std::forward<decltype(functor)>(functor), 
                std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::
        milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - ms);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << TimeElapsedOnOperation([]
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            std::cout << "\n";
    }).count() << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cout << TimeElapsedOnOperation([]
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            std::cout << '\n';
    }).count() << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It gave the following output: (Can occur differently...)

> *<1000> newlines follow...*
>
> ***2195** milliseconds* <sup>*For the string `"\n"`*</sup>
>
> *More <1000> newlines follow...*
>
> ***852** milliseconds* <sup>*For the character `'\n'`*</sup>

**2195 - 852 = 1343** milliseconds

It took *1343* (**1.343** seconds) milliseconds longer... So we can take the approximation that it was *61.18%* (*1343 / 2195 * 100*) slower than using just *`'\n'`*

This is just an approximation since the performance *can* differ in other machines...

**As to why this happens:**

1. A single character (*1 byte*) constant is much smaller (*in bytes*) than a string having a single character since a string is a [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) to char (*Points to specified addresses in memory*) which takes up more space than a single char in the memory since it is a *container* (*for [memory addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address) of each character*) after all... (*i.e,* `const char*`)...
2. There is a difference how a character and a string is read... A character is directly accessed while the string is iterated and the operations are performed for each individual character *pointed* and the result is stored back inside the address of the pointer...
3. A string is always a char array, while a char is *safely considered* an integer containing the respective [numerical value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) (*Extended ASCII, from which different **character encodings** are branched*) of it, a string of 1 character is an array of 1 character (*along with its address...*), which, in fact, is not equal to a single char...

> So maybe <sup>(*just maybe*)</sup> you are on the better side of using *`'\n'`* instead...

**However**, some "*tricky*" compiler may optimize your code from `"\n"` to `'\n'` anytime..., so, actually, we never can guess, but still, it is *considered good practice* to declare *a `char` as a `char`*...

Comment: If just outputting text, there's nothing to be "stored back". A char does not necessarily have to contain ASCII - consider the diverse ASCII extensions (ISO latin 1-15, UTF-8(!), ...)

Comment: In the case of single/dual characters (eg. newlines or other separators as naturally appearing in code), emitting single characters instead of strings representing single characters is a fair-enough (or even advisable) "habit" because the "code cost" is negligible; so it's free cake. The only issue is a generalized extrapolation that one should use `count << 'H' << 'e' .. << '\n';` instead of simply `count << "Hello world!\n";`. That is, a potential [micro-]optimization should not be used as a default pattern at the cost of code clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretical considerations only:

- A single character can be just printed out as is, a string needs to be iterated over to find the terminating null character.
- A single character can be passed and used directly as value; a string is passed by pointer, so the address must be resolved before the character(s) can be used.

So at least, the single character cannot be slower. However, a sufficiently clever compiler might spot the constant one-character string and optimise any difference away (especially if operator<< is inline).

How to test: At very first, you'd be interested in a system that might disturb the test as little as possible (context switches between threads are expensive), so best close any open applications.

A very simple test program might repeatedly use both operators sufficiently often, something like:

```
for(uint32_t loop = 0; loop < SomeLimit; ++loop)
{
     // take timestamp in highest precision possible
     for(uint32_t i = 0; i < Iterations; ++i)
     {
         // single character
     }
     // calculate difference to timestamp, add to sum for character

     // take timestamp in highest precision possible
     for(uint32_t i = 0; i < Iterations; ++i)
     {
         // string
     }
     // calculate difference to timestamp, add to sum for string
}
```

Interleaving character and string output might help to get a better average over runtime if OS activities vary during the test, the inner loops should run sufficiently long to get a reasonable time interval for measurement.

The longer the program runs, the more precise the output will be. To prevent overflow, use uint64_t to collect the sums (your program would have to run more than 200000 days even with ns precision to overflow...).